# Symfony2 redirects to /login_check after successful login (produces 404 error)

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, authentication

Weirdest problem I have ever come across. Last month I changed my firewall from ^/portal/ to ^/. Since then I've been having issues where the system will redirect back to /login/ or to /login_check/ after successful authentication. For the life of my I cannot figure out why the system will not redirect properly after login.

**Screenshot of 404. This happens when submitting login form**

(See profiler bar as the bottom. User was SUCCESSFULLY AUTHENTICATED before error occurs)
[image: 404 error after submitting login form and being logged in]

**security.yml:**

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:             ROLE_QC
        ROLE_QC:                ROLE_ACCOUNTADMIN
        ROLE_ACCOUNTADMIN:      ROLE_ACCOUNTTRACER
        ROLE_ACCOUNTTRACER:     ROLE_SALESREP
        ROLE_SALESREP:          ROLE_ACCOUNTCAPTURER
        ROLE_ACCOUNTCAPTURER:   ROLE_CLIENTUSER
        ROLE_CLIENTUSER:        ROLE_USER

    providers:
        main:
            entity:
                class: TraceGenie\PortalBundle\Entity\User
                property: email

    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous:  ~
            form_login:
                login_path: portal_login
                check_path:  login_check
                default_target_path: portalDashboard
                require_previous_session: false
                success_handler: authentication_handler
                failure_handler: authentication_handler
            logout:
                path:   portal_logout
                target: home
            http_basic:
                realm: "TraceGenie Portal"  
    encoders:
        TraceGenie\PortalBundle\Entity\User: sha512

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/_wdt/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/contact/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetPassword/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/account/save/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/qc/, roles: ROLE_QC }
        - { path: ^/accountadmin/, roles: ROLE_ACCOUNTADMIN }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

**routing.yml EXTRACT**

```
home:
    pattern:   /
    defaults:  { _controller: TraceGeniePortalBundle:User:login }

portal_login:
    pattern:   /login/ # Authenticated Anonymously
    defaults:  { _controller: TraceGeniePortalBundle:User:login }

portal_logout:
    pattern:   /logout/

login_check:
    pattern:   /login_check/
```

**Authentication Handler:**

```
namespace TraceGenie\PortalBundle\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry as Doctrine;

class AuthenticationHandler
implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface,
           AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{
    private $router;
    private $doctrine;

    public function __construct(Router $router, Doctrine $doctrine)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {

        $user = $token->getUser();
        $user->setLastLogin(new \DateTime());

        $this->doctrine->getManager()->flush();

        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) 
        {
            $result = array('success' => true);
            return new Response(json_encode($result));
        } 
        else 
        {
            if ($targetPath = $request->getSession()->get('_security.secured_area.target_path')) 
            {
                # THE BELOW WAS ADDED TO TRY AND RESOLVE INCORRECT REDIRECTION
                if ($targetPath != $this->router->generate('login') && $targetPath != $this->router->generate('home') && $targetPath != $this->router->generate('login_check')) $url = $targetPath;
                else $url = $this->router->generate('portalDashboard');
            }
            else $url = $this->router->generate('portalDashboard');

            return new RedirectResponse($url);   
        }
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) 
        {
            $result = array('success' => false);
            return new Response(json_encode($result));
        } 
        else 
        {
            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('error', $exception->getMessage());
            $url = $this->router->generate('portal_login');

            return new RedirectResponse($url);
        }
    }
}
```

**login.html.twig**

```
{% extends '::web_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 main-content" style="float: none; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">USER LOGIN <a href="{{ url("register") }}" style="float: right; padding-top: 0; padding-right: 0px;" class="btn btn-xs">REGISTER COMPANY</a></div>
            <form id="loginForm" action="{{ url('login_check') }}" method="POST">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="alert alert-success" style="font-size: 80%; font-style: italic;">
                        <p>Need Help? Try our new "HELP" feature after logging in at the top right corner of your screen. Each page has different help, with more help to be added in time.</p>
                        <p>If you feel that a specific feature needs its own help tutorial, please let us know via the helpdesk.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" name="_username" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS" value="{{ last_username }}" data-validation-error-msg="Please enter a valid email address" data-validation="email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="_password" placeholder="PASSWORD" data-validation-error-msg="Please enter a password" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min1">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" style="float:left;" onclick="$('#email').val($('#username').val()); $('#forgotPassword').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });">FORGOT PASSWORD</div>
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="log-in-user" style="float: right;">SIGN IN</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger text-center"><em>Please note that passwords are "CaSe SenSiTiVe"</em></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- FORGOT PASSWORD MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade" id="forgotPassword" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4>FORGOT PASSWORD</h4>
            </div>
            <form id="forgotPasswordForm" role="form" method="POST" class="form">   
                <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id">   
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email" class="control-label">Please enter your email address:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" data-validation-error-msg="Please enter a valid email address" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min5" onblur="this.value = $.trim(this.value);">
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="row text-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-default">RESET PASSWORD</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END: FORGOT PASSWORD MODAL -->

<script>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.validate(
    {           
        onSuccess : function($form)
        {
            if ($form.attr('id') == 'loginForm' || $form.attr('id') == 'headerLoginForm')
            {
                return true;
            }
            if ($form.attr('id') == 'forgotPasswordForm')
            {           
                $.post('{{ url("resetPassword") }}', $('#forgotPasswordForm').serialize())
                .done(function(data)
                {
                    if (typeof(data.error) != 'undefined')
                    {
                        $('#errorMsg').html(data.error);
                        $('#pageError').modal('show');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#successMsg').html('Your password has been succesfully reset and sent to your email address');
                        $('#pageSuccess').modal('show');
                        $('#forgotPassword').modal('hide');
                    }
                }); 
            }
            return false;
        },
        onError: function()
        {
            $('#errorMsg').html('Please ensure that all required fields have been filled in.');
            $('#pageError').modal('show');
        }
    });

    {% if error %}
        $('#errorMsg').html('{{error.message}}');
        $('#pageError').modal('show');
    {% endif %}
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

**UserController::loginAction()**

```
public function loginAction() #Route /login/
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $session = $request->getSession();

        if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'))
        {
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('portalDashboard'));
        }

        # If AJAX request, do not load Login page.
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) return $this->createJsonResponse(array('error' => 'Not Logged in'));

        # Get the login error if there is one
        if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) 
        {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(
                SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR
            );
        } 
        else 
        {
            $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }

        $flashError = $session->getFlashBag()->get('error');
        if (!empty($flashError)) 
            foreach($flashError as $message)
                $error = array('message' => $message);

        return $this->render(
            'TraceGeniePortalBundle:User:login.html.twig',
            array(
                'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
                'error'         => $error,
            )
        );
    }
```